# How to create Many to Many relations in prisma

Tags: javascript, prisma

I am working on a toy project using Prisma.

Requirements

1. Area models can have multiple polygons.
2. Since one polygon consists of several points, it is related to the polygon point model.
3. A polygon point has a polygonId and has x,y coordinates.

**Below is the Prisma file I wrote**

```
model Area {
  idx  Int    @id @unique(map: "idx_UNIQUE") @default(autoincrement())
  name String @db.VarChar(100)
  type String @db.VarChar(45)
  circle Circle[]
  polygon Polygon[]
  rectangle Rectangle[]

  @@map("AREA")
}

model Polygon {
  idx Int @id @unique(map: "idx_UNIQUE") @default(autoincrement())
  areaId Int
  area   Area @relation(fields: [areaId], references: [idx])
  points PolygonPoints[]
  @@map("POLYGON")
}

model PolygonPoints {
  idx Int @id @unique(map: "idx_UNIQUE") @default(autoincrement())
  x Float
  y Float
  polygonId Int
  polygon Polygon @relation(fields: [polygonId], references: [idx])
  @@map("POLYGONPOINTS")
}
```

**Below is the data I sent**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sfu6j.png)

**This is the backend code to process when that data is sent.
**

```
      const Area = await prismadb.area.create({
        data : {
            name,
            type : 'testType',
            polygon : {
              create : {
                points : {
                  create : polygon
                }
              }
            },
        },
        include : {
          polygon : {
            include : {
              points : true
            }
          },
        }
      })
```

vscode error log
How can i solve it? We need your help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZhDF.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTs9Y.png)

I tried with various changes to the code, but all failed. It's also hard to know if I'm doing the model definition of the many-to-many relationship wrong, or if I'm handling it incorrectly in the backend.

Comment: Can you show what the variable `polygon` stores?